# How to query the number of completion handlers waiting on a strand in Boost ASIO?

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, boost-asio

Is there a simple way to determine the number of completion handlers waiting on a particular Boost ASIO strand? I am aware, that that number will only be approximate in a multithreaded environment, as it can always happen, that a completion handler finishes in the nanosecond just after that counter got queried, but before the counter got returned. Or, likewise, other threads could post new work to this strand just after the counter has been queried.

But such an approximate number would already be enough for my application.

I understand, that I could add an `std::atomic<std::size_t>` variable to my application, which gets incremented, whenever something is posted to the strand, and which is decremented by each completion handler, that gets executed in that strand. But with timers, that sometimes get cancelled, and async sockets, which sometimes get closed unexpectedly, mixed in, I am quite worried, that such application based counters can easily get out of sync. So, is there an easy way to "ask ASIO itself", how much work is waiting on a partiular strand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way for that. Keep in mind that strands are like hash buckets: queues can (and will) be shared among different strands beyond a reasonable number of unique strands.

I think with executors I suspect one can easily make an executor that tracks the [`on_work_started`/`on_work_finished`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/executor.html) calls. I don't have an example of that, but I'm positive I've seen one or more in the library examples/tests.

Comment: @KaiPetzke just to be sure, don't "write an execution context". Instead it will be enough to write a custom executor, no doubt. If you need to store state, you can put it in a custom service (see https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/execution_context/use_service.html)

Comment: Yes, writing an own execution context and a matching set of executors and strands seems to be the most straightforward way to tailor those objects to one's needs, like prioritizing main tasks over secondary ones or switching from "optimize latency" to "optimize throughput" depending on relative load. To my surprise the rest of `boost::asio` including all the async network operations still works fine with custom executors and strands.

Comment: If you have work that you can share, I'm interested to see it. I'm personally a bit surprised you had to go to such lengths as to include a custom context.

Comment: I didn't find deriving from the base execution class context so complicated. If one wants to apply rules for recycling threads etc., deriving from the existing thread pool looked more complicated to me than writing the basics myself. But things aren't in a state, yet, where I could share them, but I will eventually.

Comment: That's part of why I'm so curious to see it. I'm hoping to learn from your code and perhaps dispel some unnecessary fear I have of those internals.